# “Que” vs. “Qu'est-ce que”

Tags: grammaire, questions

I have heard people use "que" in place of "qu'est-ce que", for example "Que fais-tu ?" and "Qu'est-ce que tu fais ?". Is this difference in formality, or situation? Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are equivalent in meaning. The form with the subject and verb inverted is more formal.

In general, the order of question formality from most to least looks like this:

1. Subject-verb inversion

   > Dors-tu ? Que fais-tu ? Fais-tu quelque chose ?
2. Relative clause

   > Est-ce que tu dors ? Qu'est-ce que tu fais ? Est-ce que tu fais quelque chose ?
3. Intonation alone

   > Tu dors ? Tu fais quoi ? Tu fais quelque chose ?

Note that to all appearances, *qu'est-ce* and *que fais-tu* have the exact same syntax. But in practice, *est-ce que* and *qu'est-ce que* each function more or less as a unit.

Comment: I think it's curious that for example "Que fais-tu?" is more formal than "Qu'est-ce que tu fais?", I mean I would think the less "complex" sentences would be more formal.

Comment: @BorisValderrama True, but *Qu'est-ce que* is only as formal as *aujourd'hui* — both can be decomposed into four parts, but in reality are just analyzed as one. Ask an undereducated person to spell it and they might well write "kesk"!